# Django check if reverse lookups exist in the table

Tags: python, django

I have 2 django apps which are related with a foreign key relation. The models are as follows:

**app1: models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app2.models import Student

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey('app2.Student', null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

**app2: models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app1.models import Profile

class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to achieve reverse lookups as follows in the shell:

```
>>> student_detail = Student.objects.all()
>>> student_detail = student_detail.filter(first_name='Anabelle')
>>> student_detail
[<Student: Oldham, Anabelle>, <Student: Sartain, Anabelle>, <Student: Handley, Anabelle>]
>>> b=student_detail[0]
>>> obj=b.dyslexia_profiles_set.get(student_id=student_detail[0].student_id)
>>> obj
<Dyslexia_profiles: Dyslexia_profiles object>
>>> obj.status
u'0'
```

if i give a command like the following, it would not give me anything:

```
>>> b=student_detail[1]
>>> obj=b.dyslexia_profiles_set.get(student_id=student_detail[0].student_id)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 310, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Dyslexia_profiles matching query does not exist.
```

which is true because the record does not exist for that object. How do i check if a reverse lookup exists or not in the Profile table?

I tried something like this but got an error:

```
>>> if b.dyslexia_profiles_set.get(student_id=student_detail[0].student_id).exists():
...     print("exists")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Dyslexia_profiles' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `get` to test for existence. `filter` returns a queryset, which supports the `exists` call. `get` returns a model instance if one exists, or raises an exception if one does not.

Or just catch the exception, that's OK too - and is preferable if you're going to retrieve the object if it exists.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, there may be useful helper/shortcut functions. For instance, `get_object_or_404` is useful for the common situation in which you want an object based on a URL parameter and want to return a 404 for parameters that do not match a BD record. `get_or_create` is useful when you want to record new information if necessary, and be sure that you have an in-memory object.

Comment: Use the exception as noted above, its more elegant and clean.

Comment: Depends on whether the OP actually needs the model instance, in which case the exception is better, or if the OP just needs to know whether or not a particular record exists.