# django show object from parent table

Tags: python, django

If i have a one-to-many relationship. How do i show a field from the related parent table in my child template.

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(parent)
    child_name = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
def childs(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/childs.html', {'childs': Child.objects.all(), 'parents': Parent.objects.all() })
```

childs.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>id</th>
                  <th>child name</th>
                  <th>parent name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            {% for child in childs %}

            <tr>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/childs/{{ child.id }}/">{{ child.id }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ child.id }}/">{{ child.child_name }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ child.id }}/">{{ parent.name }}</a></td>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248607/django-check-if-reverse-lookups-exist-in-the-table

Comment: @crozzfire OP is not doing a reverse lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you dont need to send the `parent` objects in the context.

You can just do `{{ child.parent.name }}` in the loop, where `child.parent` refers to the foreign key `parent` associated with the `child` model instance.

So you would just do

```
<a href="/parent/get/{{ child.parent.id }}/">{{ child.parent.name }}</a>
```

Also, you can consider optimizing the database calls using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)